# Most Efficient SQL to Calculate Running Streak Occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am looking for the most efficient manner to determine the **longest occurrence** of a streak within a given data set; specifically, to determine the longest winning streak of games.

Below is the SQL that I have thus far, and it does seem to perform very fast, and as expected from the limited testing I've done on a dataset with around 100,000 records.

```
DECLARE @HistoryDateTimeLimit datetime = '3/15/2018';
```

CTE to create result subset from voting dataset.

```
WITH Results AS (

    SELECT
        EntityPlayerId,
        (CASE
            WHEN VoteTeamA = 1 AND ParticipantAScore > ParticipantBScore THEN 'W'
            WHEN VoteTeamA = 0 AND ParticipantBScore > ParticipantAScore THEN 'W'
            ELSE 'L'
        END) AS WinLoss,
        match.ScheduledStartDateTime
    FROM

        [dbo].[MatchVote] vote
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MatchMetaData] match ON vote.MatchId = match.MatchId

    WHERE
        IsComplete = 1
        AND ScheduledStartDateTime >= @HistoryDateTimeLimit

)
```

CTE to create subset of data with streak type as `WinLoss` and total count of votes in the partition using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
WITH Streaks AS (

    SELECT
        EntityPlayerId,
        ScheduledStartDateTime,
        WinLoss,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityPlayerId ORDER BY ScheduledStartDateTime) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityPlayerId, WinLoss ORDER BY ScheduledStartDateTime) AS Streak
    FROM
        Results

)
```

CTE to summarize the partitioned vote streaks by `WinLoss` and a begin date/time, with the total count in the streak.

```
WITH StreakCounts AS (

    SELECT 
        EntityPlayerId,
        WinLoss,
        MIN(ScheduledStartDateTime) StreakStart,
        MAX(ScheduledStartDAteTime) StreakEnd,
        COUNT(*) as Streak
    FROM
        Streaks
    GROUP BY
        EntityPlayerId, WinLoss, Streak

)
```

CTE to select the `MAXIMUM` (longest) vote streak for `WinLoss` of `W` (win) grouped by players.

```
WITH LongestWinStreak AS (

    SELECT
        EntityPlayerId,
        MAX(Streak) AS LongestStreak
    FROM
        StreakCounts
    WHERE
        WinLoss = 'W'
    GROUP BY
        EntityPlayerId

)
```

Selecting the useful data from the `LongestWinStreak` CTE.

```
SELECT * FROM LongestWinStreak
```

This is the 3rd iteration of the code; at first I feel like I was overthinking and using windows with the `LAG` function to define a reset period that was later used for partitioning.

**[UPDATE]:** SQLFiddle example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b33a/1 -- Sample data for the two tables that are used above are as follows. 
 The data is meant to show the schema, and can be extrapolated for your own testing/usage;

`MatchVote` table data.

```
EntityPlayerId       IsExtMatch   MatchId              VoteTeamA VoteDateTime            IsComplete
-------------------- ------------ -------------------- --------- ----------------------- ----------
158                  1            152639               0         2018-03-20 23:25:28.910 1
158                  1            156058               1         2018-03-13 23:36:57.517 1
```

`MatchMetaData` table data.

```
MatchId   IsTeamTournament MatchCompletedDateTime  ScheduledStartDateTime  MatchIsFinalized TournamentId         TournamentTitle    TournamentLogoUrl       TournamentLogoThumbnailUrl   GameName                          GameShortCode  GameLogoUrl             ParticipantAScore  ParticipantAName    ParticipantALogoUrl   ParticipantBScore ParticipantBName    ParticipantBLogoUrl
--------- ---------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------------- -------------------- ------------------ ----------------------- ---------------------------- --------------------------------- -------------- ----------------------- ------------------ ------------------- --------------------- ----------------- ------------------- --------------------
23354     1                2014-07-30 00:30:00.000 2014-07-30 00:00:00.000 1                543                  Sample             https://...Small.png    https://...Small.png         Dota 2                             Dota 2        https://...logo.png     3                  Natus Vincere.US    https://...VI.png     0                 Not Today           https://...ay.png
44324     1                2014-12-15 12:40:00.000 2014-12-15 11:40:00.000 1                786                  Sample             https://...Small.png    https://...Small.png         Counter-Strike: Global Offensive   CS:GO         https://...logo.png     0                  Avalier's stars     https://...oto.png    1                 Kassad's Legends    https://...oto.png
```

Comment: How about some sample data?

Comment: @MJH sample data and schema has been provided in an update.

Comment: Here is a link to the SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7bb5f/5